# how to convert specific timezone into browser timezone-Js

Tags: javascript

I have a date that is in MST timezone currently displayed as:

```
Tue Dec 13 2016 16:15:04 GMT-0800 (PST)
```

now I want to get this date into browser timezone? Is there any way I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: That's not a MST timezone

Comment: Sometimes its over-kill, but [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is the best way to manipulate dates in JS.

Comment: thanks will try moment